# use of amp-img in the context of Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, amp-html

I try to use amp-img tag within jekyll
the code is

```
<amp-img
  width="16"
  height="16"
  alt="phone icon"
  scr="{{ 'assets/images/icons/Phone_number-16px-16px.png' | absolute_url }}" 
  layout="responsive">
</amp-img>

or

<amp-img
  width="16"
  height="16"
  alt="phone icon"
  scr="{{ 'assets/images/icons/Phone_number-16px-16px.png' | relative_url }}" 
  layout="responsive">
</amp-img>
```

I read the following documentation
:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img

I am sure that the absolute url leads to my image (I have tested it). But I can't see the image. Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: I am completely blocked. I checked that amp-jekyll 1.0.2 is installed in my jekyll project. But I can't see any image displayed. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I pinged the plugin developer but until now no answer. I moved forward and propose a new "header.html" wich is the following : https://github.com/flamant/fileshare/blob/master/header_1.html

But I have the following errors in console
[image]
I don't understand why it doesn't take into account my src attributes. I checked on browser each url that I wrote and it leads to the proper image. Thank you in advance

Comment: Even when I hardcode the url

Comment: finally I found what was going wrong : the attribute should be src instead of scr

Answer (score 0):

I think that I integrate in a bad way the "amp.html" file according to the documentation (https://github.com/juusaw/amp-jekyll).

I put it in the _layouts folder but without using it somewhere else. As the images I test are in _includes/header.html file which is the following:

https://github.com/flamant/fileshare/blob/master/header.html

I can't see the utility of the "amp.html" file. Shall I change it, integrate it somewhere, reference it somewhere ? Thank you for your answer